# How to avoid the flakyness that comes with "gpg --recv-key"?

Tags: continuous-integration

If you want to verify a signature of a downloaded file with gpg, you first have to import the key. Unfortunately, this operation is extremely slow and flaky in practice.

For example, here I tried it out:

```
$ gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key A0E98066
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data

$ gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key A0E98066
gpg: key B550E09EA0E98066: public key "Yichun Zhang (agentzh) <agentzh@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:  14  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 14u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2019-01-13
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

The first run failed. When I repeated, it took very long but eventually succeeded. Especially, in a CI environment, it breaks a lot, that is why I am looking for alternatives.

Question:

- How do you avoid the dependence to the remote keyserver?
- Is there an easy way to export the key as a file and use it later to import it in the CI environment without making a request to the keyserver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the key once:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key A0E98066
gpg --export A0E98066 > openresty-agentzh-A0E98066.gpg
```

Then later you can import the key without having to access the keyserver:

```
gpg --import openresty-agentzh-A0E98066.gpg
```

Comment: Will the key not be updated so now and then? If true, how could this be automated?

Comment: @030 Typically, the signatures you want to test are for releases that are already out, and the key will not change. Checking the signature is a stronger guarantee than verifying only the checksum. It is true that a key could have been revoked and you will loose the protection against it. If detecting such scenario is important, I would recommend to query the key server normally and live with the occasional breakages. You could automate the first step, too, by  regularly checking whether your exported key is still up to date and otherwise raising an alert, but I think that would be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you trust your repo or package source is to disable gpg key checking. This is especially viable if you are connecting to a repo over SSL as you can verify you are pulling the correct source and there has been no MITM attack, though you lose verification of the integrity of each individual package (in the case the repo was hacked and a rogue package inserted or package is tampered with). To do this set in your repo file:

gpgcheck=0